# Using nhibernate to filter by the value of an object in a child collection

Tags: sql, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, linq-to-nhibernate

Here's the setup.

NHibernate, Fluent NHibenrate and Nhibernate Linq

The entities invoved are

- Fault - a record of a fault occuring
- Alarm  - information about the fault, think of it as a fault type ( a list of all possible faults that can occur )
- AlarmDescription - human readable description, one for each language

A fault has an alarm and alarm has a collection of descriptions, one for each langague in the system.

An alarm can be referenced by many faults.

When a user searches one of the paramters they can search ( and order ) faults by is description.  Which means passing down the specific language to use.

The SQL to accomplish is brain dead simple to get started :

```
SELECT f.*, a.*, d.Description
FROM Fault f
JOIN Alarm a ON f.Alarm_id = a.Id
JOIN AlarmDescription d ON a.Id = d.Alarm_id AND d.Language = @lang
```

The above query would give me all fault, their alarm and the descriptions for the selected langauge.

However getting Nhibernate to generate such a query is proving difficult.

So it boils down to one of the filters being a Child Collection of Child Object of the main object.  I have tried to get this working with Linq2Nhibenrate, HQL and trying to get Native SQL to work as well.  Native SQL seems the most likley to succeed but I cannot figure out how to get the aliases to map correctly.  I'm up for any solution including changing the domain model.  This one has had me stumped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a possible HQL:

```
select f, d.Description
from Fault f
join fetch f.Alarm a
join a.Descriptions d
where d.Language = :lang
```

This retrieves a list of tuples (`object[2]`) where the first element is a Fault (with an initialized Alarm), and the second one is the description text for the selected language.

Comment: This looks like it's going to work, thanks!  I hadn't thought about joining on the child collection like that.